# How to install Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 on Win7 64b with SQLExpress 2008

Tags: ms-access, 64-bit, sql-server-express, bit

I was running VSExpress 2010 C# and SQLExpress 2008 on 32b XP.  Due to a failure I am now on Win7 64bit.  I have reinstalled VSExpress C# (64b).  I installed SQLExpress (64b) however my application uses the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 driver to connect to a Office 2007 (32b) database.  I could not get the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 to load on SQLExpress (64b).

What do I need to do to get Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 working again in SQLExpress?  Do I need to run the 32bit version? (I have downloaded it but am having problems getting it to install so I am asking while I uninstall all of my SQLExpress)

Thanks for the help.  (I saw a lot of similar issues addressed but could not find a solution for my specific problem)

Comment: May be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134827/how-do-i-use-a-32-bit-odbc-driver-on-64-bit-server-2008-when-the-installer-doesn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899201/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-64x-sql-server-and-86x-office) has the answer you're looking for -- download 64-bit version of ACE OLE DB driver. However, apparently it requires installing 64-bit version of Office as well.

Otherwise go and install WoW-enabled 32-bit version of SQL Server 2008 Express. Go to this download page and download `SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe` (note: the one **without** `32` in the file name). It should install on 64-bit system.

Comment: When I try to install the 64bit version of the ACE OLE DB driver it will not allow me due to the 32 bit version of MSOffice.

Comment: Hmn, if installing 64-bit Office is not an option, please try WoW version of SQL Server Express. I updated my answer with instructions that should work.

Comment: Okay, installing 64 bit office was not an option.  Installed SQLExpress 32b SP1.  In the properties for the provider I enabled Allow Inprocess.  The calls to the driver now work.  Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and couldn't install the 64 version because I have 32 bit office installed as well (so the 64 bit installed terminated). I changed the build of my program to x86 instead of AnyCPU and the 32 bit ACE worked [as given in this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179905/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use the 32bit version you will probably need to install the 32 bit version of the Microsoft Office Database engine. However if you have 64bit office installed this will show a message saying that 64bit is already installed.

If you install the Microsoft Office Database engine using the "/PASSIVE" command line argument it will install without the prompt, and then you can use the 32 bit ACE.OleDB.12 driver.

Beware in some situations this can cause complications with Office 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

I had to install the Access 2007 Runtime to fix this.  Here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4438