# SQL Linked Server to MS Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, installation, ms-office, linked-server

I am currently running a Windows 10 64 bit operating system and have installed Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition, also 64 bit.

Unfortunately my copy of office is MS Office 2010 32 bit and I am unable to change this.

I am currently trying to set up a Linked Server to a MS Access Database, initially under the Linked Server Providers I had no Provider to do this.  I tried installing AccessDatabaseEngine 32 bit and this still didn't show as a Provider I could use, which to be honest I expected as my SQL Server is 64 bit.

I then tried installing AccessDatabaseEngine_x64 from the command prompt using the passive command.  This worked and I could set up the linked sever but then most of my office products didn't work correctly.
Once I uninstalled the AccessDatabaseEngien_x64 everything was fine again.

How can I install the necessary drivers to connect from SQL Server to Microsoft Access without loosing the ability to use my Office Products?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to install any special software, or do any thing special. Access does not care if the server is x32, or x64 - it does NOT matter.

However, what will matter is to MAKE SURE you launch the x32 bit ODBC manager, because the one in the control panel is for x64 bit programs.

While we could hunt down the path name to launch + run the x32 bit ODBC manager, the MOST simple way to eliminate  this confusing is to simply launch the ODBC manager from Access - that way it will pick and always launch  the correct windows ODBC manager that you need.

You can choose one of the "native 11" or later drivers, or the sql server driver. The native drivers are better, but they are not installed on each workstation by default. The standard "older" sql server driver is installed on all machines by default.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but unfortunately I am not sure how to apply this to the SQL Server Linked Server connection I am trying to make.  Without the necessary driver I am unable to make a connection to the .mdb file that I need to use.

Answer (score 0):

After much googling I have managed to create the relevant connection that I needed, this was taken from another post on here :-

[Answer Used Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899201/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-64x-sql-server-and-86x-office)

I used the answer posted by serpenator to achieve what I needed to do.